# Detox with Saucelabs?

Tags: ios, automation, saucelabs, detox

Curious to see if anybody has successfully configured the Detox automation framework with Saucelabs.  I see it is mentioned on their site but they offer no support in regards to setting it up.  I'm not really sure where to start as there seems to be little to no information to go off of.

If there's a way to get Detox tests to run parallel on Saucelabs on different simulators all at once, that would be the dream for native app testing.

Comment: Have you tried integrating it? Where have you hit an issue?

Comment: I haven't been able to make much process at all.  Seems like it would require extensive knowledge of how SauceLabs operates under the hood.  I have a moderate understanding but there's not really any documentation regarding doing this.

Comment: @DespairBear Have you found a solution? I can't get it up with saucelabs either, currently I'm using a real mac device as a Jenkins slave to run detox